# How stick Iframe on top of current page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I want lo load dropdown menu from other application and want to make it as a header with iframe. Surely, dropdown menu can be expanded and thus become larger.

Usual iframe provides a scroll which allows to see all contents of iframe but it looks not good for me. I want to stick iframe on top of web page such that expanded menu items will be rendered on top of page contents. I don't want scrolls and I don't want rubber iframe. Rubber iframe may take a large amount of screen space.

[Absolute positioning](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7495800/2104560) and [z-index](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7495299/2104560) didn'd do the trick. Is there any other ways to solve this problem?

My html is the following:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
 <iframe style="height:45px;width:100%;position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;z-index:40" src="http://localhost:8080/app" scrolling="no" frameborder="0px"></iframe>
<div style='position:absolute;left:0;right:0;top:45px;bottom:0;overflow:auto;'>Your body content</div>     
 </body>
```

Comment: An `iframe` is definitely *not* the way to do this. If you want some sort of dropdown navigation your best bet would be to introduce a JavaScript file which is used across multiple pages, applied to an element with an ID which is also used across multiple pages.

Comment: dunno if it will work but maybe try adding a focus psuedo css selector to the frame and adding height:300px or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

Try the css parameter `position: fixed;`.

Good luck

Answer (score 1):

try this,I think this would solve.

```
<iframe style="height:45px;width:100%;position:fixed;top:0px;left:0px;z-index:40" src="http://localhost:8080/app" scrolling="no" frameborder="0px"></iframe>
```

Comment: put that iframe inside a div and set style="position:fixed" to the div.

Comment: `<div style="height:45px;width:100%;position:fixed;">
<iframe style="height:45px;width:100%;top:0px;left:0px;z-index:40" src="http://localhost:8080/app" scrolling="no" frameborder="0px"></iframe>
</div>` didn't help